# JDBC SQLite PreparedStatement update and delete

Tags: jdbc, sqlite

I wanted to update/delete a user specified field for a given table set up in sqlite3 via JDBC. I have used PreparedStatements for this purpose.

Now the case 3: delete sql query has no syntax error but it doesn't delete the row.

And the case 2: update sql query has syntax error - I want it to accept a field, update value and the condition.

What am I doing wrong here?

[Edit] Here's the code segment: http://pastebin.com/8naiXZ2v

```
String temp;
switch (n){
    case 1: // Insert
        System.out.println("Okay!");
        PreparedStatement inPst = con.prepareStatement("insert into " + dob.tbName + " (roll, branch, fname, lname, cgpa)" + " values(?,?,?,?,?)");
        System.out.print("Roll: ");
        inPst.setString(1, in.nextLine());
        System.out.print("Branch: ");
        inPst.setString(2, in.nextLine());
        System.out.print("Name: ");
        inPst.setString(3, in.nextLine());
        System.out.print("Surname: ");
        inPst.setString(4, in.nextLine());
        System.out.print("CGPA: ");
        inPst.setString(5, in.nextLine());

        inPst.executeUpdate();
        break;

    case 2: // Update
        System.out.println("Okay!");
        System.out.println("Fields: roll\tbranch\tfname\tlname\tcgpa");
        PreparedStatement upPst = con.prepareStatement("update " + dob.tbName + " set ? = ? where ? ;");
        System.out.print("Enter field name: ");
        temp = in.nextLine();
        upPst.setString(1, temp);
        System.out.print("Enter field value: ");
        temp = in.nextLine();
        temp = "'" + temp + "'";
        upPst.setString(2, temp);
        System.out.print("Enter condition: ");
        temp = in.nextLine();
        upPst.setString(3, temp);

        upPst.executeUpdate();
        break;

    case 3: //Delete
        System.out.println("Okay!");
        System.out.println("Fields: roll\tbranch\tfname\tlname\tcgpa");
        PreparedStatement delPst = con.prepareStatement("delete from " + dob.tbName + " where ? = ? ;");
        System.out.print("Enter key field: ");
        temp = in.nextLine();
        delPst.setString(1, temp);
        System.out.print("Enter key value: ");
        temp = in.nextLine();
        temp = "'" + temp + "'";
        delPst.setString(2, temp);

        delPst.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("Deleted!");

        break;
```

Comment: You can't parametrize conditions like that. A parameter can only be a **value**, not an object name, and certainly not a predicate. It might also be a good idea to include connection creation etc. Did you for example disable autoCommit?

Comment: Well then is there a way to form sql queries for user specified fields to update/delete the values in them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intentions are good. It is always preferable to use parameters instead of dynamic ("glued together") SQL statements. However, parameters can only be used to represent the *values* in an SQL statement. So, this will NOT work

```java
String tableName = "Clients";
String columnToUpdate = "LastName";
String newValue = "Thompson";
String columnToSearch = "ID";
int idToMatch = 1;
String sql = String.format(
        "UPDATE \"%s\" SET ? = ? WHERE ? = ?", 
        tableName.replaceAll("\"", "\"\""));
try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    ps.setString(1, columnToUpdate);
    ps.setString(2, newValue);
    ps.setString(3, columnToSearch);
    ps.setInt(4, idToMatch);
    ps.executeUpdate();
}
```

Just like we did for the table name, we have to put the column *names* inside the `PreparedStatement` text and just supply the *values* as parameters:

```java
String tableName = "Clients";
String columnToUpdate = "LastName";
String newValue = "Thompson";
String columnToSearch = "ID";
int idToMatch = 1;
String sql = String.format(
        "UPDATE \"%s\" SET \"%s\" = ? WHERE \"%s\" = ?", 
        tableName.replaceAll("\"", "\"\""),
        columnToUpdate.replaceAll("\"", "\"\""),
        columnToSearch.replaceAll("\"", "\"\""));
try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    ps.setString(1, newValue);
    ps.setInt(2, idToMatch);
    ps.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: The pre-addition of the user-specified fields work now. I do understand that in your version we're also adding the quotation marks (by escaping them) that surround the fields; but I don't understand how the regex substitution works in the string.replaceAll() - specifically the two arguments.

Comment: @sprkv5 No regex involved, just escaping `"` characters in a `"`-delimited String so `"` gets replaced with `""` to help protect ourselves against [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/).